# How to control pulseaudio automatic device switching priority?

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, defaults

PulseAudio has the ability to switch the default output on certain conditions:

- `module-switch-on-port-available`
- `module-switch-on-connect`

this is neat, but - some of these events may be false alarms. Specifically, I have a monitor connected via HDMI, and it doesn't actually support audio. Or maybe it does, but I never want to use its audio capability.

How can I create exceptions for these modules to ignore, so that the default output is never switched to some specific device?

Note: I'm using Devuan GNU/Linux 3 (Beowulf), but that shouldn't really matter.

Comment: Is there a profile for the monitor listed.  `pavucontrol` lists the profiles in the configuration section if it does you can set the profile to `off` and it won't be used.

Comment: @JasonCroyle: Nope, no profile for it.

Comment: Sorry that's the only way I know to do it.

Comment: What Jason Croyle suggested worked for me. Just for anyone else reading.

Comment: @JasonCroyle you should make your response an answer. It may not get a check mark but I'd upvote it. It was exactly what I needed.